# strange behavior during framer motion on guage

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

When guage switch value from 40 to 50 transition is like 0s, next from 50 to 60 tip go to 0 and next to 60

```
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useGauge } from "use-gauge";

interface ArcedProps {
  value: number;
}

const START_ANGLE = 45;
const END_ANGLE = 315;

export function Arced(props: ArcedProps) {
  const { value } = props;
  
  const gauge = useGauge({
    domain: [0, 100],
    startAngle: START_ANGLE,
    endAngle: END_ANGLE,
    numTicks: 21,
    diameter: 250
  });

  const needle = gauge.getNeedleProps({
    value: value ,
    baseRadius: 8,
    tipRadius: 6
  });

  return (
    <g id="needle">
       <motion.polyline
         className="fill-blue-800"
         points={needle.points}
         animate={{points: needle.points}}
         transition={{
           duration: 2,
         }}
       />
    </g>
  );
}
```

i log the needle.points
Value=40
{-7.128052193506942,3.631923997916375 -62.09485161257357,-108.65187252510869 -51.40277332231316,-114.09975852198325 7.128052193506943,-3.631923997916374: '-7.128052193506942,3.631923997916375 -62.094851612…975852198325 7.128052193506943,-3.631923997916374'}
value=50
{-8,9.797174393178826e-16 -6.000000000000023,-125 5.999999999999977,-125 8,0: '-8,9.797174393178826e-16 -6.000000000000023,-125 5.999999999999977,-125 8,0'}
value=60
{-7.128052193506945,-3.63192399791637 51.402773322313124,-114.09975852198326 62.094851612573535,-108.6518725251087 7.128052193506943,3.631923997916374: '-7.128052193506945,-3.63192399791637 51.4027733223…6518725251087 7.128052193506943,3.631923997916374'}
idk whats going on